# How to dynamically set arbitrary attributes for a class?

Tags: python

I'm trying to realize this just to see if it's possible:

And below is my current solution:

```
class A(object):
    def fset(self, x, value):
        self.__dict__.update({x:value})
    def fget(self, x): 
        return self.x
    def fdel(self, x): 
        del self.x
```

But it's not complete, the fget and fdel function doesn't work well, for example

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a.fset('z', 5)
>>> a.z
5
>>> a.fget('z')
'A' object has no attribute 'x'
>>> a.fget(z)
name 'z' is not defined
>>> a.fdel(z)
NameError: name 'z' is not defined
>>> a.fdel('z')
AttributeError: x
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python already does that by itself:

```
>>> class A(object):
    pass

>>> a = A()
>>> setattr(a, 'z', 5)
>>> a.z
5
>>> getattr(a, 'z')
5
>>> delattr(a, 'z')
>>> a.z
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'z'
```

Read the documentation on the Python [data model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Python indeeed already has this built into classes and objects by default.

- [getattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr)
- [setattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr)
- [delattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#delattr)

Your example fixed is:

```
class A(object):

    def fset(self, x, value):
        setattr(self, x, value)

    def fget(self, x): 
        return getattr(self, x)

    def fdel(self, x): 
        delattr(self, x)
```

**NB:** There isn't a lot to gain by these methods that simply wrap around the `getattr`, `setattr` and `delattr` builtins.

Comment: Actually those builtins themselves just wrap the 'magic' `__getattribute__`, `__setattr__` and `__delattr__` methods of the object iself. They can be overriden to implement custom behavior.

Comment: I wasn't going to go that far but yes :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm the OP, and I found an example on python official doc which can do the things I want [python properties](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property)

```
class C(object):

    def getx(self):
        return self._x
    def setx(self, value):
        self._x = value
    def delx(self):
        del self._x
    x = property(getx, setx, delx, "I'm the 'x' property.")
```

Let's examine it:

```
>>> c = C()
>>> c.yyy = 123
>>> c.yyy
123
>>> del c.yyy
>>> c.yyy
AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute 'yyy'
```